# CentOS 8, Debian, and Ubuntu all randomly reboot with no error log

Tags: debian, ubuntu, centos, reboot

I've looked around for answers to this question, and I can't seem to get any answer that works. My CentOS 8 system randomly reboots at intervals of around 6 hours without any log. This issue started when I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. It would restart every 2 hours or so, and even after wiping and installing Ubuntu 18.04, the issue still persisted. I checked logs and everything, but to no avail. I then tried to install Debian Buster, and that worked well for about 3 hours, and then randomly restarted. Now I'm on CentOS 8, and the interval between restarts is 6 hours, which is better, but still unacceptable for trying to run a few gameservers. I tried looking at the kernel with `dmesg`, but it just shows the machine starting. I tried looking in the system log and the only thing it records is `--reboot--` at the time of the reboot and then the startup log.

I also spoke with the server hosting service I go through, and they ran a thorough system hardware test and concluded that the hardware was alright. I have another server through them running Ubuntu 16.04 that's running the same gameserver stuff and it doesn't reboot at all.

Does anybody have any idea what could possibly be causing this?

(Also, I apologize if I haven't provided everything I need to. I'm new to this since I haven't had an issue in the past)

Comment: You could configure the server to send out kernel logs via network console to a remote system (there won't be encryption of course, which might be a problem). Maybe a log which wasn't written on disk will still be emitted via network

Comment: `sudo journalctl -b -1 -e` (on systems with `journalctl`) will show the end of the previous boot's logs. If that doesn't help, suspect power  or overheating problems, which can lead to crash/reboot.

Comment: @waltinator since it happens with different distributions (thus presumably different kernels/software), I'd rule out some sofrñtware bug, like you do.